# 2 UITableViewControllers vs 1 UIViewController that swaps two UITableViews

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller that works with two UITableViewControllers. The first UITableViewController shows the user a list of their picture libraries, and when they tap a cell, the second UITableViewController gets pushed on the stack and displays the pictures in the library (much like a UIImagePicker). What I want to do is, when a user selects a photo library on the initial UITableViewController, I want the navigation title to not animate, while the transition of UITableViews does animate. Is there a way to accomplish this, or do I need to implement a UIViewController that swaps in two UITableViews (upon then I'm not sure if I'd be able to edit the back button after the second UITableView gets swapped in?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the easiest way would be to add two UITableViews into a UINavigationController's view and just animate them with [UIView beginAnimation] in a didselectrowatindexpath. You should also have a flag to save a view state - either a library picker view is shown to user or an image picker. Then you'll be able to handle this properly in a back button selector.

That's the easiest way IMO.

Comment: So in order to do this I'd have to subclass UITableView, and make it its own delegate? How would I then load the data into the tableview, I guess it would be bad to do it within the tableview subclass, so would have to do it in the view controller itself? This seems weird and seems to violate MVC, it's suprising it's so hard to swap table views in and out without changing the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend one UIViewController and animating the frames of the table views to transition between them.

Comment: So in order to do this I'd have to subclass UITableView, and make it its own delegate? How would I then load the data into the tableview, I guess it would be bad to do it within the tableview subclass, so would have to do it in the view controller itself? This seems weird and seems to violate MVC, it's suprising it's so hard to swap table views in and out without changing the navigation controller.